# Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL Statement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I am trying to insert a value into a table from another table in my database by comparing values within my table to a variable I have captured about users from the ID number.

I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.
```

Here is the code I used to try the above:

```
    Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();

    String mySqlStatement1 = "INSERT INTO Entrant_Group VALUES (Group_Description) WHERE Group_MinAge <= " + details.getAge() + "AND Group_MaxAge >= " + details.getAge() + "AND Group_Gender = 'details.getGender()'";
    stmt1.executeUpdate(mySqlStatement1);
```

Comment: Why don't you put a semicolon at then end of the SQL statement?

Comment: Just add a Semikolon to the end

Comment: @donthedestroyer: I've never heard of an INSERT statement with a WHERE clause. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @tbodt There should not need to be a semicolon at the end of the statement, as the semi-colon is used to separate statements and are not part of the statement itself, and with JDBC you execute individual statements.

Comment: @Codo, where clauses with insert statements are quite common with with this sort of construct, "insert into t1 (fields) select values from other_tables where whatever".

Comment: @DanBracuk: That's something else. I know about the INSERT statements with a SELECT subquery. But for that a lot is missing here (SELECT and FROM clause in particular). Yet, this might be the original intention.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving the standard warnings about SQL injections attacks aside for a moment, the problem with your statement is that you put your quotes incorrectly and don't have spaces before your `AND`s:

```
String mySqlStatement1 = "INSERT INTO Entrant_Group VALUES (Group_Description) WHERE Group_MinAge <= "
 +   details.getAge()
 +   " AND Group_MaxAge >= " // Add space
 +   details.getAge()
 +   " AND Group_Gender = '" // Add space
 +   details.getGender()     // This part was enclosed in double-quotes
 +   "';";                   // Add semicolon at the end
```

To prevent injection attacks you should parameterize your query, and bind values to parameters of a prepared statement:

```
String mySqlStatement1 = "INSERT INTO Entrant_Group VALUES (Group_Description) WHERE Group_MinAge <= ? AND Group_MaxAge >= ? AND Group_Gender = ?;";
```

Comment: That's going into the right direction. But you also need spaces before the ANDs.